# What is the best workflow to import entire complex scenes from Cinema 4D to blender?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, export, geometry

I'm new here and somewhat new to exporting my scenes.

I would like to utilize the cycles render engine to speed up my render time, but still use Cinema 4D as my primary workspace.  What are the best methods to achieve this?  I'm working on a specific project that involves animation, animated textures, all sorts of reflective materials, plenty of geometry, switching cameras, and global illumination (including emission-based textures for most of the lighting).

I know this is a tall order, but I'd like to see if there's a way to get this into Blender purely for cycles GPU rendering.  I also understand that Cinema 4D will be getting cycles sometime in the "near" future, but this project can't wait that long.  Thanks in advance!

I'll be posting a similar thread within the C4D forums, but figured I'd try the blender community first as it seems you guys really know your stuff.

Comment: You can try fbx, but I'd wait for alembic support. Also interesting: Cycles & C4D integration: http://www.3dartistonline.com/news/2016/08/cinema-4d-to-get-cycles/

Answer (score 2):

FBX or Alembic will provide you with similar level of support - Static geometry import is the only thing that will be fully OK.

Animation would be supported on a rather simple and limited level (for FBX, objects and rigs animations, and shapekeys; Alembic features a fully baked animation on both object and geometry levels).

Shading support would at best be very basic (FBX supports basic shading/texturing, similar to fixed pipeline of old OpenGL e.g., afaik Alembic does not handle shaders at all?).

More scene-level things (like world) would be totally lost.

So in a word, think you should either wait for Cycles to be supported by C4D, or use whatever renderer you have currently with C4D.

A complete accurate scene export between 3D apps is (and probably will remain) pretty much impossible, unless you have the means to develop your own tools (as big studios do for their own production pipeline) - and even then, they usually only convert a subset of data betweens their apps…